# detect when class name is change jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i try to detect my spesifict class if it have a new class extra or changed

```
    $('.tab').on('click',function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
  alert('activated');
})


$('.tab').on('change', '.active',function(){
  alert('changed');
})
```

heres the code https://jsfiddle.net/k3ze0k27/

i try to use on change but its look like i make a mistake inside the function.

anyone can help me with this problem?
thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Change event not support with `a` tag .so do with some input tags.And check with class name is active or not using [`element.hasClass()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiXw_DzmNTWAhWHo48KHTijAAcQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fhasclass%2F&usg=AOvVaw0Ptl1vnAxQgyk0DzVdH4vx)

```js
$('.tab').on('click',function(){
 $(this).addClass('active');
  console.log('activated');
})


$('.tab').on('change',function(){
if($(this).hasClass('active')){
  console.log('changed');
}

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  class="tab">
```

Comment: nope it wont work. heres the updated jsfidle https://jsfiddle.net/9awLbc39/

Comment: Yess..i was already told above answer..change event only supporting input tags

Comment: so any suggestion to make it possible sir? im kinda stuck

Comment: If an element, not an input tag do with click function instead of `change`.Otherswise use input tag for change event